# GCP Data Ingestion Architecture

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am going to start working on GCP Data ingestions to BigQuery from CSVs and Data lakes and I am looking for your advice what are the technologies or architecture that I can use.

I am new to GCP but I have good understanding regarding Data Engineering technologies as I am preparing for the certification.

I tried to make a simple loading of BigQuery using Dataflow that converted to Pipeline then scheduler to run the pipeline on specific time. The problem that I have is how can I move the CSV files that has been processed to other bucket? Can I call functions to move the file?

Any advice or documentation you have is highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
CarlRoy

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If a file is in a GCP bucket it can't be "moved" to another bucket ... but a new file in a different bucket can be created using the content of the original and then you can delete the original.  However the client libraries provide wrappers to do just this ... see: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/copying-renaming-moving-objects#code-samples_2

Answer (score 1):

The question is general but I will try to help you with these few explanations.

They are many ways to apply a data ingestion architecture.

**- Solution 1 / DAG orchestration with `Airflow` and `Cloud Composer`**

You can use a data pipeline orchestrator like `Airflow` and `Cloud Composer` in `Google Cloud`.
Airflow uses `DAG` system and `Cloud Composer` uses a `GKE` cluster.
`Airflow` has the responsability to chain all the tasks of your pipeline.

***ETL example (Extract, Transform, Load) :***

```
check_csv_file_exist_input_bucket >> 
run_dataflow_job >> 
move_treaten_files_to_other_bucket
```

[Cloud Composer doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/composer-versioning-overview)

[Airflow doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/example-dags.html)

Your `Dataflow` job :

- Reads CSV files from input bucket
- Applies business rules, aggregations and transformations
- Writes results to `Bigquery`

`Dataflow` runner is serverless and it's based on `Apache Beam` model.
`Dataflow` uses autoscaling and `Beam` proposes a unified model for batch and streaming. It can be used for little, medium and big files and also long running jobs (more that one hour).
`Beam` is proposed with `Java`, `Python` and `GO` sdk.

[Dataflow doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow)

[Beam doc](https://beam.apache.org/)

In this example the transformation are applied, then the result is saved to `Bigquery`

***ELT example (Extract, Load, Transform) :***

```
load_csv_inputs_file_bucket_to_staging_table_bigquery >> 
run_task_sql_transformation >> 
run_task_sql_insertion_final_table >> 
move_treaten_files_to_other_bucket
```

In this example, files are firstly loaded in a staging table to `Bigquery`.
Then transformations are applied with `SQL`.
At the end, results are written on `Bigquery` in a final table.

**- Solution 2 / DAG orchestration with `Cloud Workflows`**

Instead of `Airflow` and `Cloud Composer`, you can use `Cloud Workflows`.
`Cloud Workflows` is a pipeline orchestrator like `Airflow` but the service is serverless.

[Cloud Workflows doc](https://cloud.google.com/workflows)

All the previous examples presented in the `Airflow` part are valids with `Cloud Workflows`.

Sometimes, if your files are not big and you don't have long running jobs (less that one hour), you can also think of using `Cloud Function V2` or `Cloud Run`.

All the technologies have pros and cons and you have to choose the services that best fit your use cases.

I share with you an article that I wrote, showing a use case with `Dataflow`, `Airflow` and `Bigquery` :

[Remove duplicates in Bigquery batch pipeline with Airflow and Dataflow](https://medium.com/google-cloud/remove-duplicates-in-bigquery-batch-pipeline-with-airflow-and-dataflow-2e7da5772c4d)